# Regex match an entire number with lookbehind and look ahead logic

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to detect if a string has a number based on few conditions.  For example I **don't** want to match the number if it's surrounded by parentheses and I'm using the lookahead and lookbehind to do this but I'm running into issues when the number contains multiple digits.

My regex:

```
(?<!\[|\{|\()(\d+)(?!\]|\}|\))
```

See here to test out my regex: https://regex101.com/r/RnTSMJ/1

Sample examples:
{2}: Should NOT Match.  //My regex Works

{34: Should NOT Match.  //My regex matches 4 in {3**4**

45}: Should NOT Match.  //My regex matches 4 in {**4**5

{123}: Should NOT Match. //My regex matches 2 in {1**2**3}

I can't figure out how to capture all of the digits in the string and then apply the look ahead/look behind logic.  Does anyone know a better way to get this behavior? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you need is `(?<![({[])\b\d+\b(?![]})])`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bvooSj/1

Comment: thanks @AhmedAbdelhameed, "\b" was exactly what I was missing.